# Ruby skipping gets after previous gets with parameter

Tags: ruby, gets

I have a multiline input using a gets parameter that works great. The problem is that it's skipping my next gets...

```
print "Multi-line response: "
response = gets("done").chomp

print "One line response: "
oneLine = gets.chomp
```

The first two lines run as expected (I can enter multiple lines of text until I type done and press enter). It then prints "One line response: " and exits the program. I never get to input for oneLine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I just logged on to see your comment in your other question.  I've updated my answer there but @itdoesntwork has it exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kernel#gets` can actually take an argument, a separator. This tells Ruby when to stop reading from stdin. If you don't provide this argument, the default value of `\n` (`$/`) is used. Here's what happens when your program runs:

- `gets` asks for everything until the first `done`.
- You type something, then type done, then hit enter. This is key, because now the input stream ends with `done\n` but `gets` has only read up till `done`.
- `gets` asks for everything until the first `\n` This `\n` is found immediately after the `done`, and `gets` already has it because you already typed it so it doesn't ask you for any more.

That's why you're not getting a chance to input anything after the first `gets`. To eliminate this problem, you should make the separator `"done\n"`, or perhaps `"\ndone\n"`, if you want it to strictly be on its own line.

Comment: Thanks for the detail! No way I would have figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

When calling `gets("done")` Ruby reads the STDIN until it finds any occurrence of `done`. This doesn't necessarily needs to be on a single line or even at the beginning or end of line. Ruby will return once you have entered a line containing `done`.

Now, Ruby will just read input until it has consumed the `done`. The rest of the input will not be read but will be kept in the buffer. Thus, in your case, if you enter a single line containing `done` into your terminal and press enter, Ruby will only consume the done but not the newline.

The newline (or generally the rest of the line following the `done`) will only be consumed by the next `gets`. Because of this, your second `gets` returns directly.

To fix this, better approach then to use the separator argument to `gets` is to use a loop:

```
response = ""
while line = gets do
  response << line
  break if line == "done\n"
end
response.chomp!
```